# Query for records that are the same in one field, but different in another?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to write a SQL query to extract records from a single table that have the same `model_number` field, but different `primary_use` fields. I have been able to query for duplicates, but my query makes no distinction if a record is truly a duplicate or if `primary_use` is different. I'm not interested in where records have the same information in both fields, only where there is a mis-match.

Comment: Essentially, the ideal query will return rows where the count of other rows in the table with the same value in the model_number field is >1, but those rows all have different values in their primary_use fields.

Comment: What DB are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQLite I believe your best bet is a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.*
FROM yourtable as t1
    INNER JOIN yourtable as t2 ON
        t1.model_number = t2.model_number AND
        t1.primary_use <> t2.primary_use;
```

Joining the table to itself where model_number is the same, but primary_use is different and then returning the distinct results should give you what you are after.

Comment: This query can be *highly* inefficient, particularly when a given model has many repeated rows with the same `primary_use`.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples would help, but it sounds like

```
select distinct model_number, primary_use from [table]
```

or perhaps

```
select model_number, primary_use from [table]
group by model_number, primary_use
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method would use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.model_number = t.model_number and t2.primary_use <> t.primary_use
             );
```

For efficiency, you want an index on `t(model_number, primary_use)`.

Alternatively, if you just want the model numbers:

```
select model_number
from t
group by model_number
having min(primary_use) <> max(primary_use);
```